# What is the best way to insert an ColdFusion application-generated identity value into an iSeries table?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, ibm-midrange, identity-column

I am working with a Database (iSeries) that does not have auto-incrementing Identity columns. Thus, I have to generate the ID on-the-fly in the application.

I have a user-defined function that accomplishes this for me, since I need to generate these IDs for several tables:

```
<cffunction name="getNewTableId" returntype="numeric" output="false">
    <cfargument name="TableName" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="ColumnName" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="SeedNum" type="numeric" required="false" default="1" />

    <cfquery name="qMaxId" datasource="#REQUEST.DSN#">
        SELECT      MAX(#ARGUMENTS.ColumnName#) AS Id
        FROM        #ARGUMENTS.TableName#
    </cfquery>

    <cfscript>
        if (qMaxId.RecordCount && IsValid("integer", qMaxId.Id))
            return qMaxId.Id + 1;

        return ARGUMENTS.SeedNum;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

*(I know this is not very secure, but this is bare-bones just to get it working int he development environment for now.)*

My question is, what are the benefits/drawbacks of calling the function from within the INSERT statement, as opposed to saving the ID value locally:

1. Generate ID inside INSERT statment

   ```
   <cfquery datasource="#REQUEST.DSN#">
       INSERT INTO MyTable            
           (
               ID,
               NameTxt
           )
       SELECT  #getNewTableId('MyTable','ID')#,
               <cfqueryparam
                   value="#FORM.MyName#"
                   cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"
                   maxlength="20" />
   </cfquery>
   ```
2. Generate ID prior to INSERT statment

   ```
   <cfset newId = getNewTableId('MyTable','ID') />

   <cfquery datasource="#REQUEST.DSN#">
       INSERT INTO MyTable            
           (
               ID,
               NameTxt
           )
       SELECT  #newId#,
               <cfqueryparam
                   value="#FORM.MyName#"
                   cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"
                   maxlength="20" />
   </cfquery>
   ```

I tend to lean towards the first option, since ColdFusion willi prepare the statement and execute it immediately, as opposed to store the value locally, and then having ColdFusion prepare the SQL statement.

Is there any difference?

Comment: I see very little difference. In both cases CF executes `getNewTableId` first. Then processes the `INSERT`. But neither option is thread safe.

Comment: DB2 have autoincrements. See @JamesA link for more information.

Comment: It might be worth talking to the DBA as to why he can not add an identity column for you.  In my environment the reason is that RPG and COBOL programs need to be recompiled because they depend on the layout of the DB tables (they iterate over the records, they do not use SQL).  To get over this I set up another schema and recreated the tables there, where I can alter the schema, now I'm tying them together with triggers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017355/db2-keeping-n-columns-in-sync-between-two-tables

Answer (score 1):

The AS/400 supports auto-incrementing identity columns using `GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY` on the column definition.

See the [SQL Reference: CREATE TABLE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmst02.htm) statement for more details.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I have no power over the ability to assign auto-incrementing IDENTITY columns in the database, so this does not help me. However, if you have a suggestion to answer my question, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry your original message was unclear that you were referring to the database schema as opposed to the database engine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Either way you seem to have the possibility of duplication.

Let us say that two user perform the same action at the same time, and the query to get the max id takes 500ms (long time, but for example purposes), this will inevitably create a duplicate id.  Two solutions:

1. Encapsulate both the getID query and the insert query in a transaction.
2. Redo your table using some sort of clustered primary key, such as id and date.

As far as wether it is better to store the id as a variable or not is a question better said as, "Am I going to use this id at any point later in this request?"

Comment: Just note, the default transaction level does *not* block other threads. So it would require a `serializable` transaction. http://www.garyrgilbert.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/15/Cftransaction-Explained  ( Though if @JamesA is correct, and auto-incrementing columns really are supported natively, that would be the best bet. )

Comment: Indeed, I was unsure when answering if the op had the ability to modify the schema.

Comment: Yes, I was not sure either. I just meant *if* he has his druthers, go with the native option ;)

Comment: I've tried using CFTRANSACTION in the past, but it throws SQL exceptions every time.

Comment: *(Edit)* What kind of exception? Does your database support them? I have never had any problems with cftransaction in other databases. I am not familiar with iSeries/AS400.